# Read a large CSV File and storing the content in C language

Tags: c, arrays, csv

I am learning C Programming and got stuck with one code. I want to read and store a large CSV file of around 10000 rows and 5 columns, each coloumn having names as time, time_diff, SN,RS, Fr.

I wrote the code for it. As I wanted to read different columns, so i used the strtok function to read from a line and store in different variables. I could read the file and print its content too on screen. But I am not getting how to store the contents in an array.

I tried to make an array of structures and then store the values in these array, But somehow it is not working. I used some random value of int variable i, just to check if it works or not.

Can someone please explain how do i store this different variables in an array and how to call them back. Like if I want to print SN[1000], then how do i store it. 
Following is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024*1024
struct Filedata {
    char *time;
    int time_diff;
    int SN;
    int RS;
    int Fr;
};


struct Filedata Data[10000];

int main ()
{
    //char buffer [BUFFER_SIZE];
    char *buffer;
    FILE *fp;
    char *token;
    int filesize;
    int i;

    if ((fp=fopen("testfile.csv", "r"))==NULL)
    {
        printf ("file cannot be opened");
    }


    buffer = (char*)malloc (BUFFER_SIZE);

    if (buffer == 0)
    {
    printf("Error: Out of Memory");
    return 1;
    }


    fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, fp);
    token = strtok(buffer, ";");


    while (token !=NULL)
    {
    printf (" \t%s", token);
    token = strtok (NULL, ";");
    }
    for (i=0; i<4;i++)
    {

        while ((fgets(buffer, filesize, fp)))

        {


            token = strtok(buffer, ";");
            Data[i].time = token;

            token = strtok(NULL, ";");
            Data[i].time_diff = token;

            token = strtok(NULL, "; ");
            Data[i].SN = atoi(token);


            token = strtok(NULL, "; ");
            Data[i].RS = atoi(token);


            token = strtok(NULL, "; ");
            Data[i].Fr = atoi(token);



            printf("\t%s\t%s\t%d\t%d\t%d\t\n", Data[i].time, Data[i].time_diff, Data[i].SN, Data[i]. RS, Data[i]. Fr);


        }
     }


    free (buffer);


return 0;

}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: why do you have your while loop in a for loop that runs 4 times?

Comment: I was just checking with some no. i,  lets say 4 to print the first 4 lines of my file. Its just an arbitrary number, but the whole idea behind the for loop was to read and print "n" no, of lines. "n" may be any no, i.e. 10,15,50 and so on..

Comment: The i variable will remain the same untill the file pointer reaches the end inside the while loop right? what exactly are you getting as output?

Comment: You dont need that for loop. while loop itself willl loop through each line in the file.

Comment: yes true, for loop does not bring me anything. I just wanted to read like first 100 lines, so thought of for loop, but it is of no use here with while loop.

Comment: Standard warning: do **not** cast `void *` (as returned by `malloc()` to other pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code had several issues. Please find the corrected version below.

Some of the issues you had:

1. Not saving result of `strtok` properly in `Filedata.time`. You need to copy string, not use assignment. So you need to allocate space for `Filedata.time` using `malloc` (don't forget to `free` each `Filedata.time` for which you allocated in such case) and copy result of `strtok` there; alternatively you can also use fixed length strings if you like.
2. Using wrong format specifier in last `printf` for `Data[i].time_diff`.
3. Not using `atoi` for `time_diff`.
4. Use of uninitialized variables. You used `filesize` variable without initializing it.

   ```
   struct Filedata 
   {
       char *time; /*increase if you like or use dynamic memory*/
       int time_diff;
       int SN;
       int RS;
       int Fr;
   };
   struct Filedata Data[ARR_SIZE];

   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {

       char *buffer;
       FILE *fp;
       char *token;
       int filesize = 0;
       int i = 0, j=0;

       if ((fp=fopen("C:\\test.txt", "r"))==NULL)
       {
           printf ("file cannot be opened");
           return 1;
       }


       buffer = malloc (BUFFER_SIZE);
       if (buffer == NULL)
       {
           printf("Error: Out of Memory");
           return 1;
       }


       fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, fp);
       token = strtok(buffer, ";");


       while (token !=NULL)
       {
           printf (" \t%s", token);
           token = strtok (NULL, ";");
       }

       while ((fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, fp)))
       {
           if(i>=ARR_SIZE) break;

           Data[i].time=malloc(256); // Use constant(or define) which is more suitable for you
           token = strtok(buffer, ";");
           strcpy(Data[i].time,token);

           token = strtok(NULL, ";");
           Data[i].time_diff = atoi(token);

           token = strtok(NULL, "; ");
           Data[i].SN = atoi(token);


           token = strtok(NULL, "; ");
           Data[i].RS = atoi(token);


           token = strtok(NULL, "; ");
           Data[i].Fr = atoi(token);


           printf("\t%s\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t \n", Data[i].time, Data[i].time_diff, Data[i].SN, Data[i].RS, Data[i].Fr);
           i++;


       }

       // Note: Also don't forget to free each  Data[i].time for
       // which you allocated space, e.g.
       for(j =0;j<i; j++) free(Data[j].time);

       free(buffer);
       return 0;



   }
   ```

Comment: Suggest `fgets(buffer, 256, fp)` --> `fgets(buffer,BUFFER_SIZE, fp)`

Comment: @chux: ok, although his BUFFER_SIZE seems unreasonably large

Comment: Issue is not if `1024*1024` is reasonable for `BUFFER_SIZE`.  The issue is that the size allocated to `buffer` should be the _same_ size passed to `fgets()`.  Had OP changed `BUFFER_SIZE` to `200`, this code's originator `256` would be a problem.

Comment: @chux: Yeah yeah I know :) Just I had left that for OP to resolve. Hope this version is helpful for him

Comment: @girogi: Thanks much for correction. Code works perfectly. I have some doubts regarding the code. It would be great if you could resolve them.  1.  Why did you use (int argc, char *argv[]) in int main()? What is its purpose?                                                                                                     2.   I am storing the values for int SN, Fr, and RS. Do I also need to declare pointers for them and then allocate the memories to these pointers as done for char variables such as time, time_diff?

Comment: @learningpal: Note time_diff is int in my code. About your 2nd question, no you can leave them as they are no necessity to declare them as pointers. Unless you don't have memory issues - because when you declare them without pointers they are stored on stack - whereas if you use malloc, data will be allocated on heap which is usually bigger (depends on your memory availability etc.-google stack vs heap allocation in C).

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have declared a char pointer for time but you have not allocated any memory to it. Hence `Data[i].time = token;` is actually not storing anything. Try allocating memory dynamically before assigning the value as in 

`Date[i].time=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*n);
strcpy(Date[i].time,token);
//replace n with the max length of the token string`

Comment: Also the `int` `time_dif` is being directly assigned to from the `char*` `token`. And of course the code is just generally wacky with extra fgets and loops.

Comment: Ofcourse. Cast the value pointed to by the char* token to an integer before assigning it to the variable time_def.

Comment: yes these variables were of int types. So i read the string from char*token and then used the atoi function to convert back to integer.